# "Give a hand" vs "help": transfer of inputs

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Can the phrase "will you give me a hand?" be used instead of "will you help me?"

'Help" in this sentence includes physical or intellectual help also. Or "help" pertaining to intelligence. Sharing of inputs related to  intelligence sources of any country, may endanger security of  country. If he can use his intellect  no harm will come to him. In conversation it is not unusual to use the phrase.

I am sorry I had to complete my question in an absurd manner. Might be weird and laughable. In the beginning of the movie "Mackenna's Gold" the phrase was used. And the unforgettable song "old turkey buzzard comprises of two lines: "They were ready to die for gold" and "They will do anything for gold"
 In this context I want to narrate an experience of mine.
 I was accompanying a lady to her house.While we were going she stretched out her hand towards me. I held her hand for a brief period.she did not request any kind of help.
 In a later year she went to the district court and requested justice for my behavior.I had pay an amount what the district court declared in judgement. 
     perhaps she complained of unusual and insulting behavior.
  Sarcastically, she gave her hand and exacted money, what kind of help is this?other than this she divulged my secrets  gossiping elaborately which can be compared to transfer of  intelligence inputs.A political movement was on,she was member of a  political party, which was inimical to us.

Comment: If none of the answers to the suggested duplicate are helpful, [edit] your question to explain why and we may be able to reopen it. You may want to read over the [Details, please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161) post.

Comment: @ColleenV-In the movie "mackena's gold",I think the movie is American.where the speaker asks for help and says"Will you give me a hand?"As the listener agreed,he handed over a piece of paper most probably of a map to the listener.A piece of paper is not a heavy thing,does not require any physical effort.According to American or British dictionary,Is the dialogue o.k? user 26375

Comment: @ColleenV-The question edited to make it a different question.Now it is not a duplicate question.please consider,Title is no longer the same. user-26375